# which resources used GCP VM instances to do any operations with GCP SQL instances?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

i am using load balancing with multiple VM instances to server more request. and i am using 1 SQL instances to store data. now i want to know which resources used GCP VM instances to do any operations with GCP SQL instances? dose my SQL instances block if more request come. if it's block how can i manage it?

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your question that you want to be able to see the operations between the GCE Instances within a load balancer.

I have found this page [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#logging) that explains how to enable login and monitoring from a load balancer, which should be useful for you.

Then you should be able to check the logs inside CLoud Loggin.